# WPF Binding: Waiting for ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, binding

I have a problem with the following binding:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TemplateDataSource}, Path=Templates}"
                     SelectedValue="{Binding Template}"
                     SelectedValuePath="Id"
                     DisplayMemberPath="Title"
                     Margin="0">
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

All my data is loaded async via WCF data services.

From time to time I get the following error (which I could trace back to the above binding)

```
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index
```

Now I guess it has something to do with the entity providing the SelectedValue (Template) being loaded before the ItemsSource. Could this be? Is there a solution to this problem, like waiting for the ItemsSource to load?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write Dummy converter on `SelectedValue="{Binding Template}"` 
You can then debug this converter to find out real cause of error.

Comment: PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High" may also help.  And I would declare the mode = .